# Monthly Temperature NetCDF in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, clip, netcdf

I tried to clip a raster layer and this sis the error I got.

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/........../Temp/processing_......................./OUTPUT.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

021-08-07T22:37:57     INFO    gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline E:\xyz.shp -cl xyz -crop_to_cutline E:/temperature_1991_2019.nc C:/Users/......................./OUTPUT.tif
2021-08-07T22:37:58     INFO    GDAL execution console output
    Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".               
    Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 2678623.0408158549 2049249.1604469456
    ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
```

Comment: It seems to  look clear: "ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid". You can create a new arbitrary polygon geometry and try clip tool again. If it works, use fix geometry qgis tool with the first polygon for trying to fix this issue.

Comment: I used fix geometry. Still I am getting error:                                        WARNING    Invalid algorithm ID for menu: qgis:creategrid                                         . .................
             Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
             
             ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 14763327488 bytes, whereas 4171672305636768 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
             
             Input file size is 15, 11